# Finite part of $-1/x^2$

Tags: integration, limits, derivatives, distribution-theory, cauchy-principal-value

I'm learning the basic of Distributional Theory. I ended up solving the following exercise: 'Find the distributional derivative of $P.V.1/x$'. After few computation, I arrived at the following:

$$\left\langle\left(P.V.\frac{1}{x}\right)', \phi\right\rangle = \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0^{+}}\bigg(\frac{2\phi(0)}{\epsilon} + \int_{|x| \geq \epsilon} \phi(x) \bigg(-\frac{1}{x^2}\bigg)dx\bigg).$$

I've discovered that $P.V.\dfrac{1}{x}$ has a short form, without the limit:

$$\left\langle P.V.\dfrac{1}{x}, \phi\right\rangle = \int_{-1}^{1} \frac{\phi(x) -\phi(0)}{x}dx + \int_{|x| > 1}\frac{\phi(x)}{x}dx.$$

Could I find a similar form for partie finie? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Partie Finie is (French?) not English, would ‘principal part’ be a good translation? Use `\langle,\rangle` to get angled brackets.

Comment: I don't think so. I suppose 'principal part' denotes a different concept. I've never found an English translation of 'Partie finie' before

Comment: I think you mean this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value

Comment: Yes, I do. This is the definition of Cauchy-principal-value. For 'partie finie' I mean exactly the limit that I wrote in the question. In Distribution theory sources, they call it $P.F. -\frac{1}{x^2}$

Comment: So, $\langle P.V. 1/x, \phi \rangle = \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0^{+}} \int_{|x| \geq \epsilon} \frac{\phi(x)}{x}dx $

Comment: The translation of "partie finie (de Hadamard)" is usually "(Hadamard) finite part" or Hadamard regularization https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_regularization

Comment: And yes, there are similar formulas without limits, such as the one I used here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3723136/the-fourier-transform-of-1-p3/3724502#3724502

Comment: https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/34E58E1057169989D3CCCD0BCD76B0DE/S0008414X00044448a.pdf/generalization_of_the_cauchy_principal_value.pdf

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4654690/principal-value-integral-on-half-interval/4659798#4659798

Comment: I don't think any of the previous answers is the exact one to my problem

Comment: The Fourier Transform of $|x|^s$ for all real $s$ was answer [HERE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/137994/fourier-transform-of-xs-and-logx/4117943#4117943).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is an analogous way to write the distributional derivative of $\text{PV}\left(\frac1x\right)$.  In fact, I used a distribution for $|x|^s$, $s\in \mathbb{R}$ in [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/137994/fourier-transform-of-xs-and-logx/4117943#4117943) to determine the Fourier Transform of $|x|^s$.

Let $\psi(x)$ be the distribution $\text{PV}\left(\frac1x\right)$.   Then, for $\phi\in C_C^\infty$ we have

$$\begin{align}
\langle \psi',\phi\rangle&=-\langle\psi,\phi'\rangle\tag1\\\\
&=-\text{PV}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\phi'(x)}x\,dx\tag2\\\\
&=-\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\int_{|x|\ge\varepsilon}\frac{\phi'(x)}x\,dx\tag3\\\\
&=-\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\int_{|x|\ge\varepsilon}\frac{\phi(x)-\phi(0)}{x^2}\,dx \tag4\\\\
&=-\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\int_{1\ge|x|\ge\varepsilon}\frac{\phi(x)-\phi(0)}{x^2}\,dx -\int_{|x|\ge 1}\frac{\phi(x)-\phi(0)}{x^2}\,dx\tag5\\\\
&=-\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\int_{1\ge|x|\ge\varepsilon}\frac{\phi(x)-\phi(0)-\phi'(0)x}{x^2}\,dx -\int_{|x|\ge 1}\frac{\phi(x)-\phi(0)-\phi'(0)x}{x^2}\,dx\tag6\\\\
&=-\int_{|x|\le 1}\frac{\phi(x)-\phi(0)-\phi'(0)x}{x^2}\,dx-\int_{|x|\ge 1}\frac{\phi(x)-\phi(0)-\phi'(0)x}{x^2}\,dx\tag7\\\\
&=-\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\phi(x)-\phi(0)-\phi'(0)x}{x^2}\,dx\tag8
\end{align}$$

And we are done.

---

**NOTES:**

Equation $(1)$ is the definition of the distributional derivative.

In going from $(1)$ to $(2)$ we applied the definition of the distribution $\text{PV}\left(\frac1x\right)$.

In going from $(2)$ to $(3)$ we used the definition of the principal value.

In going from $(3)$ to $(4)$, we integrated by parts the integral on the right-hand side of $(3)$ with $u=\frac1x$ and $v=\phi(x)-\phi(0)$.  We also exploited the fact that $\phi \in C_C^\infty$.

In going from $(4)$ to $(5)$ we split the integral into the sum of integrals.

In going from $(5)$ to $(6)$ we exploited the fact$(i)$ $\frac1x$ is odd and well behaved for $x$ bounded away from $0$ and $(ii)$ the integral of an well behaved odd function around symmetric limits is zero.

In going from $(6)$ to $(7)$ we noted that the first integral on the right-hand side of $(6)$ is not improper.

In going from $(7)$ to $(8)$ we recombined the integrals.

Comment: Could you please add explanations what is happening at each step?

Comment: @md2perpe I am almost sure that you know.  I've added some notes to explain.